Negative base exponents - how do they affect algebraic properties and equivalencies?
As a quick preface, I'm going over all my math education from school+uni after $10$ years of inactivity, and I have time to pick on these issues I never really understood, but instead just followed mechanically.
As I understand:
$a^b=c \iff \log_a(c)=b \iff \sqrt[b]{c}=a \iff c^{1/b}=a$ 
for $a,c>0 ,b$ integer
Now these are all nice and well behaved if $a>0$ and $c>0$.
My books from school are full of ways to algebraically manipulate expressions like these to their equivalents.
But these would also hold for $a,c<0$ if $b$ is odd.
Also a lot of time when these are abstract (i.e. when solving an equation or trying to prove something), there's no way of knowing if they're positive or negative, so I imagine the equivalent relations you create could be plain wrong.

i.e. $a^{b\over c}=(a^{1\over c})^{b\over1}=(a^{b\over 1})^{1\over c}=(\sqrt[c]{a})^b=\sqrt[c]{(a^b)}$ breaks down when c is even and a is negative
$(-5)^{2\over4}=(\sqrt[4]{-5})^2=\sqrt[4]{(-5)^2}$

There's also a disconnect between some books and some others where expressions like $\sqrt[3]{-27}$ are not defined at all (always when it comes to reals).
Can someone explain how to approach this or point me to a textbook I could use?
Going through my school books they keep re-defining things every time in a more general form but ideally I'm looking for a book with a top-down all-encompassing approach so I can see all these asterisks at once and where they apply. If that includes complex numbers too it's fine (but making note of when you cross into complex numbers by doing an operation/transformation).
Thanks.

When one is careful, "there's no way of knowing if they're positive or negative" is handled by splitting into cases.  $\sqrt[a]{b}$ can be the real square root when $b \geq 0$ or when $a$ is an odd integer, the complex square root when $b < 0$ and $a$ is an even integer, undefined when $b = 0$ and $a < 0$, ...  Part of the reason for "they keep re-defining things every time in a more general form" is that there are different functions (real square root, complex square root) with the same notation (where one extends the domain of the other).

@EricTowers That's what I've been doing but it would be easier and better to have a nice textbook with all the algebraic properties of these notations broken down by case.
Looking online I found out that for negative a, you need to reduce $a^{b\over c}$ to it's simplest form and take the c-th root first (if possible) - but that's just something I read online.
I guess what I'm looking for is a massive table of strict definitions of algebraic notation and "operations"/transformations of equivalencies, aimed at people with some background in math. Thanks for the input anyway though.

I don't know a good book, but the short answer is that using complex numbers enables the maths to work for $a,c \neq 0$ and any $b$. And so you can use them without worrying about the maths breaking down in this case.
Understanding complex numbers is a whole course on it's own (Welch Labs has a nice Youtube playlist explaining it), so I won't explain them properly here. But I can explain how to use them. One general representation of $a$ as a complex number is,
$$a = r e^{i (2n\pi + \theta)} \tag{1}$$
where $n$ is an integer and $r, \theta$ are real numbers with $r > 0$. $i$ is a special constant defined as $i \equiv \sqrt{-1}$. Now by convention, $r$ and $\theta$ are fixed for a complex number. But $n$ is variable because every integer value gives the same complex number in the above expression (this is clearer with the next equation).
Assuming you're comfortable with the basics of trigonometry, a key formula in complex numbers is Euler's formula,
$$e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x \tag{2}$$
So applying these concepts,
\begin{align}
a^{b\over c} &= \left(r e^{i (2n\pi + \theta)}\right)^{b\over c} \\
   &= r^{b\over c} e^{i b(2n\pi + \theta) \over c} \\
   &= r^{b\over c} \left( \cos {b(2n\pi + \theta) \over c} + i \sin {b(2n\pi + \theta) \over c}\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}
Since $n$ is variable, we get different solutions based on the values of $n$ we plug in: $0, 1, 2 \dots$
$$a^{b\over c} = r^{b\over c} \left( \cos {b \theta \over c} + i \sin {b \theta \over c}\right), \quad r^{b\over c} \left( \cos {b(2\pi + \theta) \over c} + i \sin {b(2\pi + \theta) \over c}\right), \quad r^{b\over c} \left( \cos {b(4\pi + \theta) \over c} + i \sin {b(4\pi + \theta) \over c}\right),\dots \tag{4}$$
A useful result from Euler's formula is that,
$$e^{i (2n+1)\pi} = -1 \tag{5}$$
So applying this for your examples,
\begin{align}
(-5)^{2\over4} &= (5 \times (-1))^{2\over4} \\
   &= (5 e^{i(2n+1)\pi})^{2\over4} \\
   &= 5^{2\over4} e^{i2(2n+1)\pi\over4} \\
   &= \sqrt{5} \left(\cos {(2n+1)\pi\over 2} + i \sin {(2n+1)\pi\over 2}\right) \\
   &= \sqrt{5} \left(i \right) \text{ or } \sqrt{5} \left(-i \right) \\
   &= \pm i \sqrt{5} \tag{6}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{-27} &= (27e^{i(2n+1)\pi})^{1\over3} = 3e^{i(2n+1)\pi \over 3} \\
&= 3 \left(\cos {(2n+1)\pi \over 3} + i \sin {(2n+1)\pi \over 3}\right) \\
&= 3\left({1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right) \text{ or } 3\left({-1}\right) \text{ or } 3\left({1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)\\
&= -3, \quad {3 \over 2} + i {3\sqrt{3}\over 2}, \quad \text{ or } \quad {3 \over 2} - i {3\sqrt{3}\over 2} \tag{7}
\end{align}

Thanks for the answer, I'll take a dive into complex numbers first before revisiting this. My curriculum only included a short & shallow introduction to complex numbers and it I haven't touched them in a long time.
